# State does not update until button is pressed twice

Tags: flutter, dart, tiingo

I am trying to learn and work with APIs, I am using the Tiingo Stock API to get stock info. My current app is:

```
class _StockAppState extends State<StockApp> {


String out = "Enter Ticker and press Submit";
  Map<String,String> headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization' : <API KEY REMOVED>
        };

  void getPrice(String tick) async {
    if(tick == ""){
      out = "Enter Ticker and press Submit";
    }else{
      Response rep = await get('https://api.tiingo.com/tiingo/daily/$tick/prices', headers: headers);
    if(rep.statusCode ==  200){  
      List data = json.decode(rep.body);
      Map dataS = data[0];
      out = "Price: ${dataS['close']}";
    }else{
      out = "Error";
    }
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() { 
    super.initState();  
  }

  TextEditingController ticker = new TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Stock App'),),
      body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            TextField(
              controller: ticker,
              textAlign: TextAlign.left,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: InputBorder.none,
                hintText: 'Enter Ticker',
                hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
              ),
            ),
            FlatButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
                setState(() {
                  getPrice(ticker.text);
                });
              },
              child: Text('Submit')
            ),
            Text(out),  
          ],
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

So, basically, when you enter a ticker and press submit, the app will change the "out" string var to display the stock price. But for the app to update, I am having to press submit twice.

Could anyone help?

P.S.: I have removed my API key for security reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you have async method in your `setState` method.
The `setState` method will be called synchronously.

So here problem is when `setState` is performed and frame get refreshed your data from api has not arrived yet and it showing you the old data. When you again click the button your `out` variable have new data (from your first click) which will be shown on the screen and API will be called again.

To solve your problem

```
       FlatButton(
          onPressed: () async {
            FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
            await getPrice(ticker.text);
            setState(() {
              
            });
          },
          child: Text('Submit')
        ),
```

So call the `setState` method after API call is completed.

To know more about async/await watch this video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SmTCmDMi4BY